# Accessing properties from parent class returning null while assigned in constructor

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to access the property `mysqli` from class adb inside the controller class process_loginController, just that `$this->mysqli` returns null, instead of boolean `true` (connection to database). In `process_loginController.php` I have the script that processes the login, but when I do a login I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in cf.class.php on line 3` that would be `if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT....")) {`. I did a var_dump in cf.class.php for `$this->mysqli` and it return `null`.

adb.class.php

```
class adb{
    public $mysqli; // this properties cannot be accessed 
    public $db;
    public $sql_details;
    public $hello_there;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
        $this->db = PDOManager::getInstance();
        $this->hello_there = '123';
    }
    public function url(){ // this function can be accessed
        $url = 'http://www.example.com';
        return $url;
    }
}
```

cf.class.php

```
class cf extends adb {
    public function login($email, $password, $db) {
      if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT....")) {
         // some code here
      }
    }
}
```

controller_base.class.php

```
Abstract Class baseController extends cf {

    protected $registry;
function __construct($registry) {
    ob_start();
    $this->sec_session_start();
    $this->title_of_page();
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->registry->template->is_logged_in = ($this->login_check($this->mysqli) !== false) ? true : false; // this returns what should return so it's ok
}
abstract function index();
```

}

process_loginController.php

```
Class process_loginController Extends baseController {

    public function index() {
        if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
            if ($this->login($email, $password, $this->mysqli) == true) {
                // Login success 
                header('Location: ../');
            } else {
                // Login failed
                header('Location: index.php?rt=signin?error=1');
            }
        } else {
            // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
            echo 'Invalid Request';
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried a much easier thing:

hello.php

```
require 'model/adb.class.php';
require 'model/cf.class.php';
class hello extends cf {
    public function hello() {
        var_dump($this->mysqli); // should have returned true instead NULL
        var_dump($this->url()); // this one is accessed and returns ok `example.com`
        var_dump($this->hello_there); // should have been 123 instead is NULL
    }
}
$conect = new hello;
```

Bottom line for some reason those properties are not accessible, but functions are and don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never calling your parent `__construct()`. Thus your mysqli is never created and is, yup `null`.

I know this is not codereview. But you should **never** use public properties. Just **don't**

You should also refractor your code to use Dependency Injection. Now, every cotnroller has a different mysqli object, instead of sharing the same resource.

Your methods are also doing to much, they do stuff, they handle errors, they echo output to the user, they do some redirecting, ... Keep it Stupid Simple, and go for Single responsbility

Comment: Understood, so how am I suppose to do,  based on my code, I should make the properties protected?

Comment: Depends on what kind of property they are. Is it a property that needs to be used by child classes? -> protected. Is it something you use to store internal data only used by the class it is defined in, -> private. Some even say that everything should be private, and then you write protected/public getters for those properties. Just know that the moment you declare something protected or public, it may no longer change, or you might crash your app / need a huge refractor

Comment: tried with protected but still return null, how do I call the parent construct, by instantiating?

Comment: parent::__construct()